# Azure Hybrid Connection needed for On-prem app connecting to Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

It is clear that Azure Hybrid Connection can be used to connect an Azure App service to an on prem SQL server. Is the reverse true? I have an Azure SQL instance that an on prem server needs to read and write to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely possible. Not even hybrid connection needed.

You can connect to Azure sql with connection string similar to on premise sql instance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. If your application is in .Net platform then it is much easier. You just need to go to the server explorer in visual studio and setup the connection to azure SQL database